# If our true nature is satchidananda/atman, then why is there rebirth

Tags: advaita, rebirth

Why is rebirth there if all of us are atman. Why should atma gnana be learnt for liberation.

What does learning advaita do that prevents us from getting a new birth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens to the Atman which is merely a witness. It is the subtle body (embodied self) that is affected by death and reincarnates.

> 'Just as a man gives up old garments and puts on new ones, so the
> embodied self abandons decrepit bodies and **assumes new ones**.'

**Gita 2.22**

**What happens immediately after death?**

> ‘When **he gets a new body** or abandons an old one, the Jiva, the lord of
> the body, moves, carrying them (the mind and the senses) with him, as
> the wind carries smells from their seats (in flowers and the like).’

**Gita 15.8**

Reincarnation is like us changing clothes. This does not affect us. Similarly when the subtle body changes 'clothes' (acquires new body) the Atman is unaffected.

Now the 3 questions can be answered.

**Why is rebirth there if all of us are atman?**

It is the nature of the subtle body according to Gita 2.22 and Gita 15.8 to reincarnate when the physical body dies. So we will reincarnate as long as we are associated with the subtle body.

**Why should atma gnana be learnt for liberation?**

Atma Jnana leads to the death of the subtle body and frees us from reincarnation.

**What does learning advaita do that prevents us from getting a new birth?**

Learning Advaita Vedanta does not prevent reincarnation. You have to do sravana (hearing), manana (thinking) and nidhidhyasana (meditation) and gain atma jnana to prevent reincarnation.

Answer (score 0):

because you forget your relationship to supreme consciousness. knowledge liberates us because we stop doing karma. no karma - no rebirth.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Elaborate bit more citing some sources.